# SSE intrinsics check zero flag

Tags: c++, intrinsics

I was wondering if it was possible to check the processor's flags register by the means of Intel's SSE intrinsic functions?

For example:

```
int idx = _mm_cmpistri(mmrange, mmstr, 0x14);
int zero = _mm_cmpistrz(mmrange, mmstr, 0x14);
```

In this example the compiler is able to optimize those two intrinsics to a single instruction (`pcmpistri`) and checking the flags register by a jump instruction (`jz`).

However in the following example the compiler doesn't manage to optimize the code properly:

```
__m128i mmmask = _mm_cmpistrm(mmoldchar, mmstr, 0x40);
int zero = _mm_cmpistrz(mmoldchar, mmstr, 0x40);
```

Here, the compiler generates a `pcmpistrm` and a `pcmpistri` instruction. However, in my opinion, the second instruction is redundant because `pcmpistrm`sets the flags in the processor's flags register in the same way as `pcmistri`.

So, to come back to my question, is there a way to either read the flags register directly or to instruct the compiler to only generate a `pcmpistrm` instruction?

Comment: Which compiler with what options?  This appears to be more of a question of the compilers successfully CSEing.  The ISA manual lists `_mm_cmpistrz` as one of the intrinsics for both [PCMPISTRI](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PCMPISTRI.html) and [PCMPISTRM](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PCMPISTRM.html), so according to Intel, compilers can emit either instruction for `_mm_cmpistrz`.

Comment: Also, can you wrap this in a function that compiles, so people can copy it onto http://gcc.godbolt.org/?  Or better, link to source + asm output on Godbolt yourself.

Comment: @Peter Cordes I use the MSVC compiler with all optimizations enabled  (/O2)

Comment: Looks like just an MSVC missed-optimization bug then.  gcc6.2 and icc17 successfully use both results from one PCMPISTRM (https://godbolt.org/g/4wRR8o) in a test function I wrote that branches on the `zero` result.  OTOH, clang3.9 fails, and uses a PCMPISTRI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like just an MSVC missed-optimization bug, not anything inherent.

gcc6.2 and icc17 successfully use both results from one PCMPISTRM in a test function I wrote that branches on the `zero` result ([on the Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,options:(colouriseAsm:'0',compileOnChange:'0'),source:'%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%0A__m128i+foo(__m128i+mmoldchar,+__m128i+mmstr)%7B%0A++%0A++__m128i+mmmask+%3D+_mm_cmpistrm(mmoldchar,+mmstr,+0x40)%3B%0A++int+zero+%3D+_mm_cmpistrz(mmoldchar,+mmstr,+0x40)%3B%0A++if(zero)%0A++++return+mmmask%3B%0A++else%0A++++return+_mm_setzero_si128()%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'1',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:33.530831687513725,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g62,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-Wextra++-O3+-fno-verbose-asm+-march%3Dnehalem'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+6.2',t:'0')),k:33.13583497915295,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang390,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-Wextra++-O3+-fno-verbose-asm+-march%3Dnehalem'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+3.9.0',t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)):

```
#include <immintrin.h>
__m128i foo(__m128i mmoldchar, __m128i mmstr)
{      
  __m128i mmmask = _mm_cmpistrm(mmoldchar, mmstr, 0x40);
  int zero = _mm_cmpistrz(mmoldchar, mmstr, 0x40);
  if(zero)
    return mmmask;
  else
    return _mm_setzero_si128();
}

    ##gcc6.2 -O3 -march=nehalem
    pcmpistrm       xmm0, xmm1, 64
    je      .L5
    pxor    xmm0, xmm0
    ret
.L5:
    ret
```

OTOH, clang3.9 fails to CSE, and uses a PCMPISTRI.

```
foo:
    movdqa  xmm2, xmm0
    pcmpistri       xmm2, xmm1, 64
    pxor    xmm0, xmm0
    jne     .LBB0_2
    pcmpistrm       xmm2, xmm1, 64
.LBB0_2:
    ret
```

---

Note that according to [Agner Fog's instruction tables](http://agner.org/optimize/), PCMPISTRM has good throughput but high latency, so there's lots of room to do two in parallel if latency is the bottleneck.  Jumping through hoops like using `__readflags()` might actually be worse.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself.

There is a function to read the flags register which is called `__readeflags()`. It wrappes the `pushf` (`pushfq` on x64 plattforms) instruction.

The code now looks like this:

```
__m128i mmmask = _mm_cmpistrm(mmoldchar, mmstr, 0x40);
int zero = __readeflags() & 0x40; //0x40 is the mask for the zero flag (bit 6)
```

This solution is not optimal, but it does the trick.

Comment: I'd seriously worry that optimization could separate the PCMPISTRM from the PUSHF, and lead to reading the flags from an integer add/subtract or something.  If this is reliable, then the ~5 cycles store-forwarding latency of writing flags to the stack and then TESTing them might be better than another PCMPISTRI on most CPUs, at least for throughput.  For latency, it might be worse because PCMPISTRM has good throughput but high latency, so running two in parallel to produce the same result twice might be better than an extra 5c!

Comment: You are right! I just benchmarked both solutions and the one using `pushf` is actually about 1ns slower than the one using `pcmpistrm` and `pcmpistri` in parallel.

Comment: Careful that your benchmark reflects your real use-case.  Latency vs. throughput is a big deal.